# Getting data from extra column in pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Can't get column data from pivot table these are my models

Products

```
 public function users()
  {
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany('App\User')
        ->withTimestamps()
        ->withPivot('auth_product');
  }
```

User

```
 public function products()
 {
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany('App\Products')
        ->withTimestamps()
        ->withPivot('auth_product');
 }
```

controller

```
$authorized_users = Products::find($id)->pivot->auth_user;
```

it gives "Trying to get property of non-object". I'm trying to get boolean value

EDIT: Succeded to get value but now giving "null" value

```
$authorized_users = Products::find($id)->first()->pivot['auth_user'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$authorized_users = Products::find($id)->pivot->auth_user;
```

This is fine. Make sure you have that specific `$id` in products table.

You can check with the first record:

```
$authorized_users=Products::first()->pivot->auth_user;
```

Comment: it's giving null but there is value in that column under product_id(which serves as foreign key), but it still throws out null